# Using conditionalpanel in shiny where input is a vector

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I have a number of inputs that I would like to have to filter a data source. However, I have 100s of inputs to render but I expect only a handful will be used at any one point in time.

I don't want to render them all just in case because it could make the page cluttered and difficult to navigate. I was hoping to make all the widgets, and use a conditionalpanel to check if it appears on the list before displaying it.

The problem I have is that in the condition argument within conditionalpanel I can't seem to the %in% operator, it doesn't give me an error - it just doesn't work.

I've made a lightweight example below:

```
# libs ----
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# header ----
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Example")

#sidebar ----
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(disable = T)

#body ----
body <- dashboardBody(

  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12,
      selectInput(
        inputId = "control", 
        label = "choose something:",
        choices = c("a", 
                    "b", 
                    "c", 
                    "d", 
                    "e"),
        multiple = TRUE
      )
    )
  ),

  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "'a' %in% input.control",
    textInput(inputId = "bla", label = "aaaaa")
  ),

  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "'b' %in% input.control",
    textInput(inputId = "ble", label = "bbbbb")
  )

)

# all ui ----
ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = header, 
  sidebar = sidebar, 
  body = body
)

# server ----
server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {


})


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I haven't been able to find a way to solve this issue, appreciate any help!

thanks

**EDIT -- solved**
the condition is a JS expression (thanks to @edavidaja for the heads up on that) and when I tried to use:
`condition = 'input.control.includes("a")'` it failed. 
so worked out a solution with a JS dev colleague of mine and got the solution with...
`condition = 'input.control && input.control.indexOf("a") > -1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the help:

```
condition   
A JavaScript expression that will be evaluated repeatedly to determine whether the 
panel should be displayed.
```

`%in` is an R expression, rather than JavaScript one, so something like [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is probably what you need.

Also, if you have hundreds of things to render that you may not need, consider using `renderUI()/uiOutput()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Think I'm going to have to try `renderUI / uiOutput` - I tried using `input.control.includes()` but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: That's for letting me know it was a JS expression - I got the solution with the following condition.

`condition = 'input.control && input.control.indexOf("a") > -1'`